# Referencing a DAX Measure in another Measure in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, measure

I have some DAX which I'm trying to use another measure value in the below measure code

```
Aggregated_Amount = CALCULATE(
    CALCULATE(
    sum('Total'[Value]),
    REMOVEFILTERS('Dates'[Week])
    ),
    Dates[Week]>=[velocity_min_week],
    Dates[Week]<=[velocity_max_week]
)
```

But I'm getting the below error:

A function 'PLACEHOLDER' has been used in a True/False expression that is used as a table filter expression. This is not allowed.

Essentially what I'm trying to do is show the aggregate volume from the Table "Total" based on the range set by the Context filter, but not break it up into weeks (like a "fixed aggregated range amount").

So I built a Min and Max from a Splicer ("velocity_min_week" and "velocity_max_week") to override the context filter instead.